# The Lifetime of a Type

Tags: java

What does the resolution process (sub step of linking) mean in Java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Java specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/12.doc.html),

> Resolution is the process of checking
>   symbolic references from [some class] to
>   other classes and interfaces, by
>   loading the other classes and
>   interfaces that are mentioned and
>   checking that the references are
>   correct.

In other words, figuring out exactly which other classes a piece of code is referring to, and are those classes compatible with the usage being made, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on it ?

Comment: I probably could. What about this concept is giving you difficulties? If class `A` has a method `foo` that calls method `bar` on class `B`, resolution means checking that there really is a class `B` and it has a method `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JVM](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) specification:

**[5.4.3 Resolution](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#73492)**
*The process of dynamically determining concrete values from symbolic references in the runtime constant pool is known as resolution.*